# MS-Access Calculating Percentage of returned values

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013

I need to create a query that analyzes the values returned by a calculated field and tell me what percentage of them are a certain value within the course of a year.

My calculated field references a table that classifies positions by a letter code. The field uses this :

```
Occ: IIf([Position] Is Null,"",(IIf([PosCode]="O" Or [PosCode]="S","Specialized","Traditional")))
```

to show if each position is considered `specialized` or `traditional`. 
I need the `Query` to count the number of specialized positions and calculate what percentage of the population they make up. *EDIT: The Query already selects positions that were active during a certain time frame as specified by criteria in another field.* I figured another calculated field would be my best bet, so I tried making a calculated field with the Count total but didn't get anywhere.

I'll be honest, I'm pretty green at this, so I'm likely missing something obvious. Hopefully that's enough info to go on. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count and sum:

```
Select
    Count(*) As Total,
    Abs(Sum([PosCode]="O" Or [PosCode]="S")) As Specialized
From
    YourTable
Where
    [Position] Is Not Null
```

To get the percentage in one go:

```
Select
    Abs(Sum([PosCode]="O" Or [PosCode]="S")) / Count(*) As SpecializedPercentage
From
    YourTable
Where
    [Position] Is Not Null
```